# BackgroundDownloader Max Parallelism

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-async

Is there a way to set the max number of concurrent downloads from `BackgroundDownloader`?

This is roughly what I'm doing.

```
var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
foreach( var uri in uriList )
{
    var download = downloader.CreateDownload( uri, storageFile );
    download.StartAsync().AsTask( cancellationTokenSource.Token, progress );
}
```

I'd like to be able to set a max download parallelism of say 4. Is this built in, or do I need to manage this myself?

If I need to manage this myself, what is the recommended way? I have thought about just doing a `Parallel.ForEach` and setting the max amount there, but I don't know if that's a good solution.

Comment: I wonder if you could do something like put all of the `Task`s into 3 buckets: `Queue`, `Downloading`, `Done`. Using `Task.WhenAny` on the `Downloading` list, remove that task and put it in the 'Done' list, then `dequeue` and start one, adding it to `Downloading`.

Comment: Could you put together a working example and post it as an answer? I've tried a few different ways here, and nothing is working quite right. Doing it as `Parallel.ForEach` works, but then the callback is on another thread, and I'm having issues getting things to run on the `CoreDispatcher`. I'd rather do everything using async/await too if I can; especially since the download operations are async already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing. This isn't complete, but it's the gist of it.

```
private void StartDownloadsAsync()
{
    var downloadQueue = new Queue<DownloadOperation>();
    // Create all the download operations and add them to the queue.
    await CreateDownloadsAsync();
    var maxConcurrentDownloads = 4;
    var loopAmount = Math.Min( maxConcurrentDownloads, downloadQueue.Count );
    for( var i = 0; i < loopAmount; i++ )
    {
        DownloadAsync();
    }
}

private void DownloadAsync()
{
    var download = downloadQueue.Dequeue();

    HandleDownloadAsync( download ).ContinueWith( task => DownloadComplete( download ) );
}

private void DownloadComplete( DownloadOperation download )
{
    // Update progress counter here.

    if( downloadQueue.Count > 0 )
    {
        DownloadAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        // Downloads are done. Do something.
    }
}

private async Task HandleDownloadAsync( DownloadOperation download, bool isActive = false )
{
    if( !isActive )
    {
        await download.StartAsync().AsTask( cancellationTokenSource.Token );
    }
    {
        await download.AttachAsync().AsTask( cancellationTokenSource.Token );
    }
}
```